# Excel - Odd Page Layout

Tags: microsoft-excel

Having some trouble with getting the page layout in excel the way I need it. For some reason columns A & B go onto the first page with the subsequent columns going onto the next page.

[image]

I have checked the page break preview and it doesn't show anything untoward.

[image]

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Have you set the print area?

Comment: Yeap I reset that but it didn't solve it.

Just found a rogue page break that wasn't showing in the page break view - all sorted!

Comment: Did you create the file yourself or did it come from somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

Found a rogue page break that didn't appear in the page-break view. This was solved by using the Page Layout - Breaks - Reset all page breaks feature.